# How do I decode an object array and retrieve it from userdefaults?

Tags: ios, swift, encoding, decoding, userdefaults

I have an `array` with type `[NotificationTriggers]` that I would like to store in `userdefaults`. To do that, the data needs to be `encoded` and `decoded`. I have followed tutorials here:

https://cocoacasts.com/ud-5-how-to-store-a-custom-object-in-user-defaults-in-swift

and here:

https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/system/how-to-load-and-save-a-struct-in-userdefaults-using-codable

But I still get an error that I can't seem to solve.

I have an `extension` of `userDefaults` where I do the magic in the get and set of the variable. `NotificationTriggers` `Struct` looks like this:

```
struct NotificationTriggers: Equatable, Codable {
    var doorName: String
    var notificationTrigger: String
}
```

`Encoding` seems to work, but in `decoding` I get an `error` saying

> Cannot convert value of type '[Any]' to expected argument type 'Data'

This is the code:

```
extension UserDefaults {
    var notificationTrigger: [NotificationTriggers] {
        get {
            if let data = self.array(forKey: UserDefaultsKey.notificationTrigger.rawValue) {
                do {
                    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                    //CODE BELOW PRODUCE ERROR
                    if let decodedData = try decoder.decode([NotificationTriggers]?.self, from: data) {
                            return decodedData
                    }
                } catch { }
            }
            return []

        }
        set {
            do {
                let encoder = JSONEncoder()
                let data = try encoder.encode(newValue)
                    
                self.setValue(data, forKey: UserDefaultsKey.notificationTrigger.rawValue)
                
            } catch { }
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried `casting` the data:

```
UserDefaultsKey.notificationTrigger.rawValue) as? Data // get warning "Cast from '[Any]?' to unrelated type 'Data' always fails"

UserDefaultsKey.notificationTrigger.rawValue) as? [NotificationTriggers] // get error "Cannot convert value of type '[NotificationTriggers]' to expected argument type 'Data'"
```

Not sure what's missing here. Any ideas?

Comment: `self.array(forKey:` => `self.data(forKey:` , and `[NotificationTriggers]?.self` => `[NotificationTriggers].self` should do the trick. Also, in the `catch`, don't just do nothing, instead: `catch { print("Error while doingSomethingToCustomizeHere :\(error)") }`

Answer (score 5):

You save `Data` for the key `UserDefaultsKey.notificationTrigger.rawValue` with:

```
let encoder = JSONEncoder()
let data = try encoder.encode(newValue)
self.setValue(data, forKey: UserDefaultsKey.notificationTrigger.rawValue)
```

So the first mistake I see:

```
if let data = self.array(forKey: UserDefaultsKey.notificationTrigger.rawValue) {
```

`array(forKey:)`? No, `data(forKey:)`, you didn't save an `Array`, you saved a `Data`, a `Data` that might after some decoding "hides" an `Array`, but the system doesn't know it.
So, it should be:

```
if let data = self.data(forKey: UserDefaultsKey.notificationTrigger.rawValue) {
```

Then:

```
let decodedData = try decoder.decode([NotificationTriggers]?.self, from: data)
```

=>

```
let decodedData = try decoder.decode([NotificationTriggers].self, from: data)
```

Also, it's bad habit to have `catch { }`, if there is an error, you might want to know it:

```
catch {
    print("Error while doingSomethingToCustomizeHere: \(error)")
}
```

Comment: Ah, very nice, I learned something today :) Thank you so much for clearing that up @Larme